Issue with parsing in snowflake query
We are parsing s3 path in snowfalke query to fetch the partition_id for each table.
Wrote a query its working fine if the part-*.parquet files present under the partitions.
Giving a wrong results if the parquet files having with different names.
Aim is single query should return partition_id=20240101 in both the use cases.
use case1 working fine as expected:
select split(split(split_part('1234/local/table_name1/partition_id=20240101/part-0001.parquet','table_name1'),'part-')[0],'/')c

output : 
partition_id=20240101

use case2 giving output - partition_id and parquet file also
select 
split(split(split_part('1234/local/table_name2/partition_id=20240101/table.name2.parquet','table_name2'),'part-')[0],'/')c

output: 
partition_id=20240101
table.name2.parquet

I have to tweak the query so it should work in both cases and returns only partition_id=20240101. Please share your inputs.
Thanks in advance

any inputs please

the code you provided doesn't even run.  You are missing a parameter for split_part().

If the partitions are always at the same level of your S3 bucket path, you could simply use 1 split_part function and choose the right "part":
with x (str) as (
  select *
  from (values('1234/local/table_name2/partition_id=20240101/table.name2.parquet'),('1234/local/table_name1/partition_id=20240101/part-0001.parquet'))
)
select split_part(str,'/',4) as arr
from x
;

Output:
partition_id=20240101
partition_id=20240101

Per your added requirements:
with x (str) as (
  select *
  from (values('1234/local/table_name2/partition_id=20240101/table.name2.parquet'),('1234/local/table_name1/partition_id=20240101/part-0001.parquet'))
)
select case when split_part(str,'/',4) ilike 'partition%' then split_part(str,'/',4)
            when split_part(str,'/',4) ilike 'year%' then split_part(str,'/',4) || '/' || split_part(str,'/',5)
       end as arr
from x
;


Thanks for the details, Can I use split_part to return the positions for the given range, For examples I have partitions like below also '1234/local/table_name2/year=2024/month=01/table.name2.parquet'. Here output should be year=2024/month=01

you'd likely need to use a case statement to determine when to pull the 4th part vs. the 4th+5th part.  Updated the answer to show what I'm referring to.  If you have more cases, you can just add them to the list.

Is there a way to ignore the last part of the string, examples /partition_date=20240101/part-0001.parquest,/year=2024/month=01/file_name.parquet, /partition_id=20240102/file_name2.parquet. Is there a way to exclude that *.parquet file so I will get the output like partition_date=20240101, year=2024/month=01, partition_id=20240102

It should already be doing that, since that'd be a different part of the split.  You keep changing the requirements.  Maybe just know that using a SPLIT creates and array and then you can do whatever you want with the array.  SPLIT_PART chooses which array part to return.
